# $58^{5745} \pmod{59}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Trying to solve the modular equation $$x \equiv 58^{5745} \pmod{59}$$

I've seen a solution to this that involves using that $58 \equiv (-1) \pmod{59}$, and this in turn means that $58^{5745} \equiv (-1)\pmod{59}$, but I'm missing the rule that explains this step.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: @ArnaudD. No. OP has the solution, but is looking for an explanation. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Properties): compatibility with exponentiation. This is provable by induction (or binomial theorem).

Comment: $58\equiv -1\mod 59$ holds because of $59\mid 58+1$. Hence we can replace $58$ by $-1$. Since the exponent is odd, the result follows.

Comment: @player3236 - That's a great resource, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $58 \equiv 59-1\equiv -1\pmod{59}$, $58^{5745}\equiv (-1)^{5745}\equiv (-1)\cdot ((-1)^{2})^{2871}\equiv \boxed{-1\pmod{59}}$